# DELETE request in redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I'm writing a React Redux CRUD App with Node.js API. I'm struggling with **DELETE** part.
I'm receiving the successful delete message but nothing has changed in my database. [Successful Message in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsnkW.jpg)

I just wonder why it's not deleting any data?

**user.reducer :**

```
import { userConstants } from '../_constants';

export function users(state = {}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case userConstants.GETALL_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true
      };
    case userConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS:
      return {
        items: action.users
      };
    case userConstants.GETALL_FAILURE:
      return { 
        error: action.error
      };
    case userConstants.DELETE_REQUEST:
      // add 'deleting:true' property to user being deleted
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.map(user =>
          user.id === action.id
            ? { ...user, deleting: true } 
            : user
        )
      };
    case userConstants.DELETE_SUCCESS:
      // remove deleted user from state
      return {
        items: state.items.filter(user => user.id !== action.id)
      };
    case userConstants.DELETE_FAILURE:
      // remove 'deleting:true' property and add 'deleteError:[error]' property to user 
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.map(user => {
          if (user.id === action.id) {
            // make copy of user without 'deleting:true' property
            const { deleting, ...userCopy } = user;
            // return copy of user with 'deleteError:[error]' property
            return { ...userCopy, deleteError: action.error };
          }

          return user;
        })
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**user_actions:**

```
export const userService = 
{
    delete: _delete,
};


function _delete(id) {

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'DELETE',
        // headers: authHeader(),            
    };

    return fetch(`/removeadmin/${id}` , requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}
```

**AdminListPage component :**

```
delete(){

this.props.dispatch(userActions.delete(this.state.delete_user._id));

}
```

Also, in server-side I'm receiving a successful delete status

[ServerSide Console(200)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZJvz.jpg)

**Server_Side router:**

```
 app.delete('/removeadmin/:id', function(req, res)

{

        var sent_url = url.parse(req.url, true),
            qdata = sent_url.query, 
            sent_id = qdata.id;
        console.log('id ' + sent_id);

        admin.removeadmin(sent_id, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                throw err;

        });
```

**Server_Side delete function:**

```
 module.exports.removeadmin = function(id, callback){
     var query = { _id: id };
     Admin.remove(query, callback);
    };
```

I have deleted a user by simple fetch command in the component without redux and I have sent id in the body of delete request and it was working but with redux just successful message.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why do you need delete action in reducer ? Your state should reflect your database. I don't get our state above. Don't remove data from state manually, just fire the action and delete from the db on successful delete, return all users and then replace the existing list from your state with the new list . Doing that will ensure your state is the total reflection of your db. I don't get what you are doing above. Simplify your state at the most you just need ADD_LIST action type , IS_FETCHING, DID_INVALIDATED etc. actions in your reducer.

Comment: @NuruSalihu I wanted to do the delete through the redux. I have followed an example to do so. Yes, you are correct, I should not remove data from state manually. In simple fetch I did it but with redux no. Thank you

Comment: @AmrAly No , two different port

Comment: @Nafis can you update your reducer above, and leave the delete case/action that is failing ? Now its long and confusing. Leave the code that fails only. Then we will look at the state action. Or can you tell me what is the action type that is failing ?

Comment: @NuruSalihu Thank you Nuru, I have added my answer to this, and it's working. But I'll be happy if tell me why do I should not have delete in reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in the post should work except for the fetch request the url should be prepended with the backend url so if the backend url is `localhost:3000` your fetch should be:

```
return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/removeadmin/${id}`, 
requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
```

and in your serverside router you can access your id param like so:

```
app.delete('/removeadmin/:id', function(req, res)
{
   var send_id = req.params.id;
    admin.removeadmin(sent_id, function(err, user) {
       if (err)
          throw err;
});
```

Comment: Yes, this one also is working well now for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I made a mistake in URL. So on the server in URL I can't have access to my id and it showed me undefined.

Just I have changed these lines :
user_action:

```
return fetch(`/removeadmin?id=${id}` , requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
```

and server_side router:

```
app.delete('/removeadmin?:id', function(req, res){
```